# How do I install jmeter on a Mac?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

We want to use JMeter.

I've downloaded the production version as directed in the user manual at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

But how do I get started and install the software?

I don't know java and I can't find any instructions on what I'm supposed to do with the download.

I am on a Mac.

How do I install the product as a usable program?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

The easiest way to install it is using Homebrew:

```sh
brew install jmeter
```

Plugins are now included

And to open it, use the following command (since it doesn't appear in your Applications):

```
open /usr/local/bin/jmeter
```

If it crashes while opening, use the following command.
don't forget to replace your current version.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.6.2/libexec/bin/jmeter
```

if you have newer macbook try this:

```
open /opt/homebrew/bin/jmeter
```

Comment: switched to this as I use and prefer homebrew

Comment: Not working!

$ brew install jmeter
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz
==> Best Mirror http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "jmeter"
Download failed: http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz

Comment: @thusharaK You'll need to run "brew update" as the recipe is pointing to an older version 2.11 of jmeter than the one currently hosted by the mirror 2.12.

Comment: If some one suffer from broken of drag & drop or copy & paste, remember to launch from click instead of ternimal.

Comment: thanks @Adam, if anyone wants more detail https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/10/26/how-to-install-jmeter-mac/

Comment: I get: Error: invalid option: --with-plugins.  But it works without that, thx

Comment: This is not working in later version if mac

Comment: Hello, just did this and couldn't get jmeter to run. Looks like it was placed in a different directory. Adding this comment for future users.

```open /opt/homebrew/bin/jmeter```

Comment: The directory for me was also `/opt/homebrow/bin/jmeter` but if in case it changes in the future, i found out where the directory is using `which jmeter`

Comment: For me`jmeter` command actually opens up the application

Answer (score 122):

jmeter is now just installed with

> brew install jmeter

This version includes the plugin manager that you can use to download the additional plugins.

OUTDATED:

If you want to include the plugins (JMeterPlugins Standard, Extras, ExtrasLibs, WebDriver and Hadoop) use:

> brew install jmeter --with-plugins

Comment: I'd favor this answer over the other one, because it's always a pain when you work on someone else's test plan to discover that they are using a plugin you don't have and that you have to uninstall and reinstall with homebrew. Just install with all plugins and be done with it (except if your intent is to catch test plans that use plugins when they shouldn't, of course).

Comment: just downloading the jar and running it is faster, unless you have brew set up. (As described directly below by Laurent Bristiel)

Comment: I see this error with command above
`==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "jmeter"
Download failed: http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz`

Comment: I have an updated brew version and when I install this it seems corrupted. Installing jmeter without plugins and then getting the plugins seperately seem to be the best bet.

Comment: I ran `brew update` and then ran above command but I am getting this error `Error: invalid option: --with-plugins`

Comment: It seems they've updated the install process. Now, simply issuing `brew install jmeter` brings the "Plugins Manager" menu option (which you can use to visually install the desired plugins)

Answer (score 56):

Install jmeter using the following command

```
brew install jmeter
```

then open it using this

```
open /usr/local/bin/jmeter
```

Answer (score 34):

1. Download apache-Jmeter.zip file
2. Unzip it
3. Open terminal-> go to apache-Jmeter/bin
4. `sh jmeter.sh`

Comment: Just like to add this worked for me on my Mac. For below config:
MackBooPro:
Apple M1 Pro - 32GB 
MacOS: Ventura 13.2.1

Answer (score 17):

Once you got the ZIP from the download, extract it locally, and with your finder, go in `bin` directory.

Then double-click on `ApacheJMeter.jar` to launch the ***User Interface of JMeter***.

This and the next steps are described in a [blog entry](http://biscminds.blogspot.fr/2011/12/quick-jmeter-setup-on-mac.html).

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 options:

- Install using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

`brew update` to update homebrew packages

`brew install jmeter` to install jmeter

Read this [blog](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/using-homebrew-to-install-and-configure-jmeter-under-mac-osx/) to know how to map folders from standard jmeter to homebrew installed version.

- Install using standard version which I would advise you to do. Steps are:

  1. Install Last compatible [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) version (7 or 8 as of JMeter 3.1).
  2. Download JMeter from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
  3. Unzip folder and run from the folder:

`bin/jmeter`

Answer (score 3):

Download last version (not 2.5.1 or other old ones) from jmeter.apache.org

Unzip file

Ensure you install a version of JAVA which is compatible, Java 6 or 7 for JMeter 2.11

In bin folder click on jmeter.sh not on jar or execute `sh ./apache-jmeter-x.x.x/bin/jmeter` in the terminal.

x.x.x is the version you use.

Finally, when started you may want to select System Look and feel for Mac OSX better integration.
Menu > Options > Look and Feel > System

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install it is using Homebrew:

```
brew install jmeter
```

Plugins are now included

And to open it, use the following command (since it doesn't appear in your Applications):

```
open /opt/homebrew/bin/jmeter
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to this.
I have followed this process to start the application in Mac:

1. I downloaded `apache-jmeter-3.3_src.zip` from
   http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi website.
2. I extracted the files and then move to bin folder and then you
   can find a file named `jmeter`, this is an executable file. Right click
   on this and open with terminal and wait for 5 minutes, that's it.

Thank you, I hope this might help.

Answer (score 2):

Using brew

```
brew install jmeter
```

To navigate to the folder

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter
```

Note: You can create an alias, to open this often.

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick video guide to cover below 2 steps
[Install Jmeter on Mac in 2 Minutes](https://youtu.be/fkKshhrTSFo)

Step 1: Install Homebrew (If not already present)

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Run above command from the terminal (https://brew.sh/)

Step 2: Install JMeter using Homebrew package Manager
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jmeter#default

```
brew install jmeter
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you download the and unzip the file from the apache site,

- Right click and select `new terminal at folder`
- In the terminal type `cd bin`
- Then type `sh jmeter.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I installed JMeter with SDKMAN, so the path to the executable is different from Homebrew. Nevertheless I created the workflow to start JMeter including the option to drop test file on.

[image]

Comment: so how did you ran it?