# jmeter is not downloading using brew in mac osx

Tags: macos, curl, jmeter, homebrew

I tried to install jmeter by following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610316/how-do-i-install-jmeter-on-a-mac) but I fail and got below error

> $ brew install jmeter
>
> ==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz
>
> ==> Best Mirror http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
>
> Error:Failed to download resource "jmeter" Download failed:
> http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/apache/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz

**Why is this? Is the link broken and how to replace it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to first update brew:

- brew update

Then retry it again, as it should download jmeter 2.12 not 2.11.

Also if you want to download jmeter-plugins with it, you can use:

- brew install jmeter --with-plugins