# No jmeter.properties file when installed with brew?

Tags: jmeter

I installed jmeter with brew and built a test plan which I hoped to be able to run on a distributed set of nodes. But I cannot find where the jmeter.properties file is in order to tell my local client where to look for the helper nodes. Any ideas? I tried adding it manually, but it did not take.

The /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin folder only contains jmeter and jmeter.log

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098634/jmeter-is-not-downloading-using-brew-in-mac-osx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into [JMeter formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jmeter.rb) my expectation is that you should see *jmeter.properties* file under `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/libexec/bin/` folder (this is applicable for [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5), for other versions location should be different)

---

PS1. You can install JMeter without using Homebrew, if you execute the following commands:

```
cd ~ 
wget https://www-eu.apache.org/dist//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.0.tgz
tar xf apache-jmeter-5.0.tgz
```

then you will have "normal" JMeter installation as `apache-jmeter-5.0` in your [home folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55408/how-can-i-see-my-home-folder-in-the-finder)

PS2. According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#properties) you should be rather using *user.properties* than *jmeter.properties* so consider placing your configuration into `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/libexec/bin/user.properties` file instead

PS3. You can also pass any JMeter property via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) so you can do something like

```
jmeter -JpropertyName=propertyValue
```

i.e.

```
jmeter -Jremote.hosts=10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Comment: Thanks. The file was not in the location you specified, so I uninstalled it with homebrew and installed it manually. Now everything is there. Thanks!

Comment: Found it under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/5.5/libexec/bin/jmeter.properties` as of today 2023-06-21

Answer (score 2):

It's also not in my `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin` folder.

However, if your intention is simply to have jmeter load your user.properties file, then

1. create a user.properties file inside
   `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin`
2. then execute jmeter by running `$ /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/jmeter`

The user.properties file would be loaded by jmeter.